# Method of slicing strings starting at the first blank space

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, indexing, slice

I believe my professor taught us a way to begin parsing through a string at the first occurrence of a blank space (or any character for that matter) but I seem to have forgotten it. I'm trying to slice through a sentence starting at the first letter of the second word. Can anyone give me some help?

The code would receive a string similar to that shown below:

```
'Donald Springman 50 98.0\nKenneth Clarke 52 97.3\nRon Martin 51 95.5'
```

What I need to do is sort the strings by the given last names.  So what I am hoping for is a way to simply bypass the first word in the string, and start parsing at the first space, therefore starting at the second word.

Comment: I *think* `<string>.find(" ")` will be helpful to you.

Comment: Can you give us a simple example?

Comment: Donald Springman 50 98.0
Kenneth Clarke 52 97.3
Ron Martin 51 95.5

the code would return a string similar to that shown above. What i need to do is sort the string by the given last name. So what I am hoping for is a way to simply bypass the first word in the string, and start parsing at the first space, therefore starting at the second word.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the extra details you have provided.  They will be overlooked if they're hiding in a comment like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean is:

```
string = 'word1 word2 word3'
print(string[string.find(' ') + 1:])
```

outputs:

```
'word2 word3'
```

Comment: thank you! but this also forces me to have to split the string into multiple strings at each \n. What is a good method to do this?

Comment: do you mean `lines = string.split('\n')` and then the solution I proposed above for every line?

Comment: yes, I think that's what I mean. I'll give it a try.